# Unexpected result using unique inside a data.table

Tags: r, unique, data.table

Given a data.table  (vith version 1.9.5)

```
TEST <- data.table(1:20,rep(1:5,each=4, times=1))
```

If I run this:

```
TEST[unique(V2)]
```

I get this result:

```
   V1 V2
1:  1  1
2:  2  1
3:  3  1
4:  4  1
5:  5  2
```

Is it really the intended beahaviour or a bug?
Or I'm just not using it properly?

I was reading the "R book" and in an example they use  TEST[unique(Vegetation),] and say it's intended to select a subset of rows unique for the vegetation.

I expected to get something like

```
   V1  V2
1:  1   1
2:  5   2
3:  9   3
4:  13  4
5:  16  5
```

Though I understand that would need to specify an aggregation criteria.

Comment: Can you explain why you are surprised by this result? `unique(V2)` gives `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and since you have this in i you get the first 5 rows. Could you possibly want it in j, i.e., `TEST[,unique(V2)]`?

Comment: I reply you on the main question

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `unique` does.

Comment: A somewhat convoluted way of using similar syntax: `setkey(TEST,V2); TEST[J(unique(V2)),mult="first"]`

Comment: Fyi, The R Book does not cover data.tables.

Comment: @Frank, it doesn't cover data.tables but it covers dataframes, the exercise I'm speaking about is at page 121. I've just tried to apply it to data.tables. Oh, wait, I've just seen the new version of the R book uses !duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TEST[,unique(V2)]` gives `[1] 1 2 3 4 5`. Since `TEST[1:5]` is supposed to give you the first 5 rows and that's what you get, there is no bug.

To get your expected result, you can do this:

```
TEST[!duplicated(V2)]
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  1
#2:  5  2
#3:  9  3
#4: 13  4
#5: 17  5
```

or this:

```
TEST[, V1[1], by = V2]
#   V2 V1
#1:  1  1
#2:  2  5
#3:  3  9
#4:  4 13
#5:  5 17
```

or as @Arun reminds me there is now a data.table method for `unique`:

```
unique(TEST, by="V2")
#   V1 V2
#1:  1  1
#2:  5  2
#3:  9  3
#4: 13  4
#5: 17  5
```